# Modern page using SPFx

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, navigation, modern-experience

I am new to the SPFx framework, I do not know **how to use `SPFx` in modern site page**.

How to customize the navigation bar in a modern site page and how to increase the navigation bar?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Go to `http://{your_siteurl}/_layouts/15/AreaNavigationSettings.aspx`. 
You can customize here in the "Global Navigation" section.

You don't need SPFX for this.

You can learn about SPFX from the [samples](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/master/samples)

Comment: Thanks for your response bro.. In site navigation we can customize the top link bar but In modern site page, I need to customize size of navigation bar and apply color for it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use SharePoint Framework(SPFx) Extension to extension to achieve that. Follow this MS doc for more: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/overview-extensions

Just remember that the changes made through SPFx extension will be reflected ONLY on modern pages, not the classic pages(e.g: Site Contents, Site Settings).